# How to run Selenium IDE testcase.html with Firefox using Windows CMD

Tags: batch-file, selenium-rc, selenium-ide, windows-7-x64

I've read up on how to execute the selenium IDE testcase.html using selenium-server RC. Here is how I have it setup...

```
C:\Selenium_Server\selenium-server.jar
C:\Scripts\Q2Nightly.html
```

If I open Firefox and open the testcase with the Selenium IDE, it will run fine. Executing it from the command line is not working for me, and I need it to as part of an automated batch file.

Here is the command I am using:

```
java.exe -jar C:\selenium_server\selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://127.0.0.1" "c:\Scripts\Q2Nightly.html" "c:\Scripts\results-firefox.html" -port 5555
```

CMD Output

```
Apr 14, 2013 11:32:33 AM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
11:32:34.661 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.9-b04
11:32:34.662 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 x86
11:32:34.667 INFO - v2.32.0, with Core v2.32.0. Built from revision 6c40c18
11:32:34.731 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:5555/wd/hub
11:32:34.732 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
11:32:34.732 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
11:32:34.733 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
11:32:34.733 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
11:32:34.755 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@1833955
11:32:34.756 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
11:32:34.758 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5555
11:32:34.758 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@e4f972
jar:file:/C:/Selenium_Server/selenium-server.jar!/customProfileDirCUSTFFCHROME
11:32:34.857 INFO - Preparing Firefox profile...
11:32:36.008 INFO - Launching Firefox...
11:32:36.967 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
```

Screen shot of the two firefox windows opened:

http://s116.photobucket.com/user/xXxghaleonxXx/media/Selenium_Automated_zps11713a8a.png.html?sort=3&o=0

After this nothing happens. The testcase isn't executing and even manually the run button won't work. Can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save `Q2Nightly.html` as a test **suite** not as test **case**. That will solve the issue.

Comment: Fantastic! This worked thanks so much. Now I just need to find out how to automate the authentication check pop up. But I guess that is another question.

Comment: By authentication check, do you mean the windows dialog box asking for username and password ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023869/how-to-automate-username-password-fill-for-firefox-authentication-popup-using-se

I was able to find the answer. It was a popup window for "authentication required"

Comment: @FiddleFreak Yes i have seen that question yesterday. I use AutoIT for that authentication box.