# Logging to internal sites using user name and password in Firefox

Tags: authentication, user-interface, selenium, automated-tests, windows-authentication

I am writing automated user interface testing using Selenium. Our website uses Windows Authentication. Our deployment tests run on a user account that doesn't doesn't have permission to all the URLs we are making requests to, and hence the browser shows the authentication dialog. This causes a timeout in my deployment tests while waiting for someone to enter the credentials. Is there any way I can specify the user name and password in Firefox (which is the browser I am using with Selenium) so that it doesn't show any dialog?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will allow you to bypass the windows authentication:

http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/firefox-auto-login-with-windows-authentication-and-ad/

From the link:

> To enable this in Firefox with a simple configuration change.
>
> Go to the address bar, and enter the following:
>
> about:config
>
> You will be prompted with a warning, so just confirm that “I’ll be
>   careful, I promise!”. Now go to the filter bar, and enter this string:
>
> network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris
>
> Double-click this value and add the domain of your intranet website,
>   ex. “michelsen.dk”

Edit:

If you are trying to log in as a different user than your logged in user, then you will probably need to use AutoIT.

Some more discussion on this issue here:
[How to automate username/password fill for firefox authentication popup using selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023869/how-to-automate-username-password-fill-for-firefox-authentication-popup-using-se)

Comment: No, this will only pass the credentials of the currently logged in user. I want to specify credentials manually.