# How to handle window alerts to access intranet (Sharepoint) using Selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, selenium-ide

When click on sharepoint link, it alerts below authentication for **username** & **password**

[image]

Is there any way to handle this authentication **?**

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"?

Comment: I don't want to type username & password manually on each attempt. Is there any code to ignore this manual typing ?

Comment: Take a look at this, should give you what you need

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023869/how-to-automate-username-password-fill-for-firefox-authentication-popup-using-se

Comment: Yes but on this link _Fiddle Freak_ found the solution by using **AutoIT**. What is the solution in **Selenium VBA** or how to convert below code into Selenium VBA ?

`WinWaitActive("Authentication Required")

Send("Username")

Send("{TAB}")

Send("Password")

Send("{ENTER}")`

Comment: any suggustion ? which pertinent to the subject matter.

Answer (score 1):

With the credentials in the URL (Basic Authentication only):

```
Dim driver As New IEDriver
driver.Get "http://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth"
```

With the SetCredential method (not implemented with all the drivers):

```
Dim driver As New IEDriver
driver.Get "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth"

Dim dlg As Alert: Set dlg = driver.SwitchToAlert(Raise:=False)
If Not dlg Is Nothing Then
  dlg.SetCredentials "admin", "admin"
  dlg.Accept
End If
```

With WScript (only works locally):

```
Dim driver As New IEDriver
driver.Get "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth"

Dim dlg As Alert: Set dlg = driver.SwitchToAlert(Raise:=False)
If Not dlg Is Nothing Then
  Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  wsh.SendKeys "admin"
  wsh.SendKeys "{TAB}"
  wsh.SendKeys "admin"
  dlg.Accept
End If
```

With AutoIt (only works locally):

```
Dim driver As New IEDriver
driver.Get "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth"

Dim dlg As Alert: Set dlg = driver.SwitchToAlert(Raise:=False)
If Not dlg Is Nothing Then
  Set aut = CreateObject("AutoItX3.Control")
  aut.Send "admin"
  aut.Send "{TAB}"
  aut.Send "admin"
  dlg.Accept
End If
```

To get the latest version in date working with the above examples:
https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/latest

Comment: _Thanks for your support [florentbr](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2887618/florentbr) :) and I just want to confirm, is there any way to use below codes on **Firefox** driver?

`Dim driver As New IEDriver`
`driver.Get "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth"`

`Dim dlg As Alert: Set dlg = driver.SwitchToAlert(Raise:=False)`
`If Not dlg Is Nothing Then`
`dlg.SetCredentials "admin", "admin"`
`dlg.Accept`
`End If'

Comment: Sure: Dim driver As New FirefoxDriver

Comment: Not Working :( **( I think it cannot be implemented with all the driver)**